# Error in running project on Android studio

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run a project on Android Studio which I have downloaded from an Udemy tutorial. I successfully imported the zip file to Android Studio but when I am running the project its showing that errors: `cannot Run git` and `please fix the sdk.dir property in the local properties file`

Comment: So to clarify... You extracted the Zip file and then imported, right?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to go into your `local.properties` file and change the path of the `sdk.dir` property to point to your SDK. The `cannot run git` is a separate problem altogether and will not stop you from running your application.

Comment: I am a beginner so it will be great if you explain how should I proceed for path change

Comment: In the "Project" view of Android Studio expand "Gradle Scripts". Under it, you'll find the local.properties file. double-click it to edit and change the path of the `sdk.dir` property to point to your Android SDK.